# Перевод на страницу по нажатию кнопки

Tags: javascript, jquery, button

Есть кнопка:

```
 <button id="s1">vk.com</button>
```

Скрипт на jquery

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $('s1').onclick(function (){
        location.href="https://vk.com/feed";
    });
});
```

Но перехода по ссылке нет,библиотека подключена правильно,нужно именно на jquery.
Помогите найти ошибку,я что-то не понимаю

Comment: Чем стилизованная ссылка не подходит?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Во-первых не `onclick`, а `click`

Во-вторых не `$('s1')`, а `$('#s1')`

```js
$(document).ready(function (){
  $('#s1').click(function (){
      console.log(666);
      //location.href="https://vk.com/feed";
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="s1">vk.com</button>
Скрипт на jquery
```